# Which is the right tense for talking about past activities that are true in the present as well

Tags: grammar, past-tense, complex-sentences

In the following sentences:

A: I read an interesting book last week related to space, the name of the book **was** Death by Black Hole

B: I read an interesting book last week related to space, the name of the book **is** Death by Black Hole

Which is correct: **IS** or **WAS** ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: . . . have been reading . . .

Comment: they're both right

Answer (score 1):

In basic English, both of them are correct, nevertheless, when you say the book's name **was**... you're expressing that the name was Death by Black Hole and may, but doesn't have to be anymore - Either way, you say that the book's name was it at the point when you were reading it.

However, this is a tiny detail, which may even be unnoticeable in spoken English.